# js: proper way to use optional chaining?

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused as to where in a nested object the optional chaining is used...if I have a nested object like this:

```
obj = {
   obj1: {
     name: "o",
     obj2: {
       name: "X",
       obj3: {
         name: "Y",
         obj4: {
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

should I just be using `?.` at every level for safety like:

```
obj?.obj1?.obj?.obj2?.obj3?.obj4
```

or would I only need it at the top level?

Comment: [Use it at every level](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es2020-is-here-360a8304b0e6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use it *right after* a property that might be nullish.

For example, if `obj` may either be undefined, or the object in the question, you'd do:

```
obj?.obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4
```

```js
const getVal = obj => obj?.obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4;

console.log(getVal({
   obj1: {
     name: "o",
     obj2: {
       name: "X",
       obj3: {
         name: "Y",
         obj4: {
         }
       }
     }
   }
}));
console.log(getVal());
```

Or, if `obj` is always defined, and the only thing that might not exist is the nested `obj3` property, you'd do:

```
obj.obj1.obj2.obj3?.obj4
```

```js
const getVal = obj => obj.obj1.obj2.obj3?.obj4;

console.log(getVal({
   obj1: {
     name: "o",
     obj2: {
       name: "X",
       obj3: {
         name: "Y",
         obj4: {
         }
       }
     }
   }
}));
console.log(getVal({
   obj1: {
     name: "o",
     obj2: {
       name: "X",
     }
   }
}));
```

Use `?.` right after every possibly-nullish expression.